# F# Constructor

Tags: f#

How do I do things in a constructor in F#? I cant quite figure it out...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would check out [Constructors (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192(VS.100).aspx):

> Objects of class types have
>   constructors. There are two kinds of
>   constructors. One is the primary
>   constructor, whose parameters appear
>   in parentheses just after the type
>   name. You specify other, optional
>   additional constructors by using the
>   new keyword. Any such additional
>   constructors must call the primary
>   constructor.