# Define concise F# class with post constructor logic

Tags: f#, idioms

For this class definition:

```
type Foo(f1: int, f2: string) =
member x.F1 = f1
member x.F2 = PostProcess f2
```

Will PostProcess (some string manipulation function) gets called every time f2 is accessed? If the answer is yes and I want to avoid it, what’s the right idiom? Is this one below recommended? It is a bit too verbose for me.

```
type Foo =
val F1: int
val F2: string

new (f1, f2) as this = 
    {F1 = f1; F2 = f2;}
    then this.F2 = PostProcess(f2) |> ignore
```

Comment: Vaguely related question which might be of interest to anyone landing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624571/how-to-invoke-methods-from-constructor-in-f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original definition `F2` is a read-only property and the `PostProcess` function will be called each time it is accessed.  This is easy to verify:

```
let PostProcess s = printfn "%s" s; s

type Foo(f1: int, f2: string) =
  member x.F1 = f1
  member x.F2 = PostProcess f2

let f = Foo(1,"test")
let s1 = f.F2
let s2 = f.F2
```

Here's how I'd write the class to only process once:

```
type Foo(f1: int, f2: string) =
  let pf2 = PostProcess f2
  member x.F1 = f1
  member x.F2 = pf2
```

Comment: Perfect! I also verified myself. And your proposal looks good and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, properties are re-evaluated every time (e.g. just like a `get` property in C#).

See @kvb's answer for a succinct answer to your particular question.

In general, see e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192(VS.100).aspx

http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!894.entry

for language information on the best way to write class constructors.  The concise summary is that you should use a 'primary constructor' (as you have, the parens right after the type name that take constructor arguments), and then use `let` and `do` at the top of the class as the constructor body.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the pointers. I am just starting to use the OOP aspects of F#.