# F# constructor syntax - overiding and augmenting new

Tags: syntax, f#, constructor

I have a non-disposable class with Open/Close syntax that I'd like to be able to `use`, so I'm trying to inherit from it, and work the Open into the `new` and the Close into Dispose.

The second part is ok, but I can't work out how to do the Open:

```
type DisposableOpenCloseClass(openargs) =
    inherit OpenCloseClass()
    //do this.Open(openargs)  <-- compiler no like
    interface IDisposable
        with member this.Dispose() = this.Close()
```

(cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624571/how-to-invoke-methods-from-constructor-in-f) which I asked a long time ago, but I can't join the dots to this one)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Key is `as this`:

```
type OpenCloseClass() =
    member this.Open(x) = printfn "opened %d" x
    member this.Close() = printfn "closed"

open System

type DisposableOpenCloseClass(openargs) as this = 
    inherit OpenCloseClass() 
    do this.Open(openargs)
    interface IDisposable 
        with member this.Dispose() = this.Close() 

let f() =
    use docc = new DisposableOpenCloseClass(42)
    printfn "inside"

f()
```

Answer (score 4):

As Brian suggests, you can use the `as this` clause. However, in F#, it is usually recomended to use subclassing (inheritance) only when there is a really good reason for that (e.g. you need to implement some virtual class and pass it to a .NET library).

If I was implementing your example, I would probably prefer function returning `IDisposable` using a simple *object expression*:

```
let disposableOpenClose(openargs) = 
  let oc = new OpenCloseClass() 
  oc.Open(openargs)  
  { new IDisposable with
      member this.Dispose() = oc.Close() }

let f() =
  use docc = disposableOpenClose(42)
  printfn "inside"
```

To some point, this is just a personal preference, but I think it is a preferred option, because it is simpler than using inheritance (although I don't have any document to link here :-)). Also, the compiled code may be a bit simpler, because handling `as this` may require some runtime checks.

Comment: Thanks, in my particular case, I needed access to other functions on the 'base' class, so just returning the interface wouldn't be enough.